# Element still there after .remove()?

Tags: jquery

'I'm trying to sum values of elements when they are added, edited or removed. I'm having a hard time updating the sum after I have removed the element which contained the value.

There is a delete button on which there is an "onClick" event which will fire some wrapper function for the jQuery function .remove().

HTML:

```
onClick="RemoveElementById('someId'); return false;"
```

Javascript:

```
function sumEverything() {
    var total = 0;
    $('span[id*="days"]').each(function() {
        var value = $(this).html;
        if (IsNumeric(value)) {
            total += parseFloat(value);
        }
    });
    $('.sumClass').html(total);
}
```

I'm trying to update the sum once the element is removed. So I tried this:

```
$(.ButtonArea input).click(function() {
    sumEverything();
 });
```

Problem is that the sum stay the same... Is there any way to "know" when the element is properly removed? I've tried, for example:

```
onClick="RemoveElementById('someId'); return false; sumEverything();"
```

But that didn't quite do it either.

Comment: Don't return before you call `sumEverything`, otherwise you're introducing a short exit (making `sumEverything` unreachable).

Comment: Obviously the attempt where you return before you actually sum anything won't work. Perhaps putting the return *after* you sum. Or wrapping it up in a single method.

Comment: Fix the syntax error and use `$(".ButtonArea input")`. Btw, if you have jQuery available there is no reason to use inline attribute event handlers.

Comment: are your elements text fields?

Comment: Try to use classnames isntead of ID's

Comment: BradChristie, DaveNewton: That didn't help :(. 
Bergi: Can't seem to find the syntax error?
Jon Fabian: My elements are <span>'s (generated by horrible code-behind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd use a different approach than defining onClick inside every element.

Let's say you have some elements that looks like this now;

```
<div id="someId" onClick="RemoveElementById('someId'); return false;"></div>
<div id="someId1" onClick="RemoveElementById('someId1'); return false;"></div>
<div id="someId2" onClick="RemoveElementById('someId2'); return false;"></div>
```

change it to this (adding a class to every element, and removing the onClick);

```
<div id="someId" class="uniqueClassName"></div>
<div id="someId1" class="uniqueClassName"></div>
<div id="someId2" class="uniqueClassName"></div>
```

then add an onClick listener in JavaScript;

```
// The reason I'm using .live() instead of .on() is because .on() only
// affects elements that exists in the document when DOM is loaded and
// not elements that are added after page load

$(".uniqueClassName").live('click', function() {

    // Either do this
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        RemoveElementById(id);

    // Or this
        $(this).remove();

    // After removing the element calculate total
    sumEverything();
});
```

The reason it's not working now is because you have 2 onClick on the same element, and the one that updates the sum() is executed before the one that removes the element, that's my guess from what I can see (you can always test this by utilizing console.log())

Comment: I do however having trouble "finding" my delete buttons. They are dynamically created from a ASP.NET template using clone. The clone method attaches a click event to the button. I cannot change this. `$('.DynamicDeleteButtonArea').find('input').live('click', function() { sumEverything });`  will not work. I cant find that delete button no matter what I try. I can find those who are not "cloned".